# Interactive auto-suggest?

Tags: completion, minibuffer

My current configuration of Emacs (24.5.1 on U15.10) has auto-suggest set up for `find-file`, that is, when I do C-x C-f, the mini-buffer fills with possible completions that I can tab to and hit enter to select. I'd like to do that on an interactive function I'm writing where it would auto-suggest each element of this list

```
((thing1a . thing1b) (thing2a . thing2b) ... )
```

Is there boilerplate code for this someone knows about?

Comment: Have you tried just using `icomplete-mode`? That presents completion candidates in the minibuffer, and you can choose any of them by hitting a key. `C-h f icomplete-mode RET`.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "auto-suggest"?  Do you mean `auto-complete`, or something like `helm` or `ido-mode`?

Comment: Yes, `ido-mode` is enabled and that's the sort of behavior I'm looking for. Sorry I didn't mention this.

Comment: Found http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings and am looking at  `(ido-completing-read "What, ... is your favorite color? " mylist)` section. Need it to work with my list.

Comment: . . . seems like I need to convert the list elements to strings to fit into `ido-completing-read`

Answer (score 3):

With a combination of `ido-completing-read` and a conversion of the list items to strings, we may achieve this effect:

```
(setq mystrlist (mapcar (lambda (l-item) (format "%s" l-item)) mylist))
```

then

```
(ido-completing-read "What is your favorite thing? " mystrlist)
```

Running this should pop up each list item as a possible completion.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use code like this:

```cl
(let ((lst '(("John" . "John Smith")
             ("James" . "James Bond"))))
  (assoc (completing-read "Test" lst) lst))
```

Here, `lst` is an alist, which is a valid collection type to pass to
`completing-read`.  If you want `completing-read` to use Ido, use
`ido-ubiquitous` to set `completing-read-function` accordingly.  But
the code above automatically will adapt to whatever completing mode
you have (default/helm/ido/ivy).